# How to properly use autoincrement

Tags: sql, syntax-error, h2

I am trying to create a database of accounts that automatically increase by 1 after every new insertion, but when I try to insert something into the table it throws this error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (USERACCNAME=[*]'admin',USERIP='lol', USEREMAIL='somehing', USERPASSWD='74123', USERPREMIUM='-1', CHAR1='1', CHAR2='-1', CHAR3='-1', CHAR4='-1') "; expected ",, )"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO account (userAccName='admin',userIP='lol', userEmail='somehing', userPasswd='74123', userPremium='-1', char1='1', char2='-1', char3='-1', char4='-1') [42001-171]
```

This is the insert that causes the error

```
updateDatabase("INSERT INTO account VALUES(" +
                "userAccName='admin'," +
                "userIP='lol', " +
                "userEmail='somehing', " +
                "userPasswd='74123', " +
                "userPremium='-1', " +
                "char1='1', " +
                "char2='-1', " +
                "char3='-1', " +
                "char4='-1')");
```

I have tried entering inserting into the table including userAccID

```
updateDatabase("INSERT INTO account VALUES(" +
                "userAccID='1'," +
                "userAccName='admin'," +
                "userIP='lol', " +
                "userEmail='somehing', " +
                "userPasswd='74123', " +
                "userPremium='-1', " +
                "char1='1', " +
                "char2='-1', " +
                "char3='-1', " +
                "char4='-1')");
```

However it throws this when I run it

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "USERACCID" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO account VALUES(userAccID='1',userAccName='admin',userIP='lol',userEmail='somehing', userPasswd='74123', userPremium='-1', char1='1', char2='-1', char3='-1', char4='-1') [42122-171]
```

The SQL structure looks like this

```
create table if not exists account(
    userAccID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userAccName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    userIP VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userEmail VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userPasswd VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userPremium INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char1 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char2 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char3 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char4 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'
);
```

This is what the UpdateDatabase Method looks like (In case it is the source of the problem)

```
public static int updateDatabase(String statement){
    int SQL_Status = -1;
    Statement SQL_Statement = null;
    try {
        SQL_Statement = connection.createStatement();
        SQL_Statement.setQueryTimeout(20);  // set timeout to 20 sec.
        SQL_Status = SQL_Statement.executeUpdate(statement);
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SQL_Status;
}
```

Basically I am trying to have it structured like this

```
id=1, accName=admin, userPasswd=x
id=2, accName=user1, userPasswd=y
id=3, accName=user2, userPasswd=z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer:**

Could you create the table like this instead? Note the use of IDENTITY...

`create table if not exists account(
    userAccID IDENTITY,
    userAccName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    userIP VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userEmail VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userPasswd VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    userPremium INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char1 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char2 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char3 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    char4 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'
);`

**Edited answer:**

I see: you were trying to insert all attributes, even the primary key useraccid. Usually a bad idea. Let me explain why...

When creating new SQL records, if such primary key was created with autoincrement policy, you just need to insert any the other attributes (provided you do not violate a SQL constraint like `NOT NULL`) and a new useraccid will be created through an internal counter.

If you need to modify/update an existing record, you'll need to perform a filter `WHERE` but you'll update only the modified attributes and useraccid will remain the same. Please refer to H2 manual (http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update) if in doubts.

So if you need to insert a new record without primary key useraccid in the request, then the correct SQL command for h2 is:

`INSERT INTO account (userAccName,userIP,userEmail,userPasswd,userPremium,char1,char2,char3,char4) VALUES ('admin','lol','somehing','74123',-1,1,-1,-1,-1)`

Please note that in the H2 web console, you can try the following loop command, inserting 100 times the same values and creating 100 records:

`@loop 100 INSERT INTO account (userAccName,userIP,userEmail,userPasswd,userPremium,char1,char2,char3,char4) VALUES ('admin','lol','somehing','74123',-1,1,-1,-1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're using quotes to enter an integer into the column of type INT ? which means you're entering string into a column of type integer ?

try this.. maybe works

```
"INSERT INTO account VALUES(" +
            "userAccName='admin'," +
            "userIP='lol', " +
            "userEmail='somehing', " +
            "userPasswd='74123', " +
            "userPremium= -1, " +
            "char1= 1, " +
            "char2= -1, " +
            "char3= -1, " +
            "char4= -1 )"
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is still throwing the same error :[

Comment: were you even able to create the table ? I mean are you sure if there is a table in the database ? Did you check ? Since you're using quotes in the createTable method as well.

Comment: This type of SQL will not work with H2. The correct command is ```INSERT INTO account (userAccName,userIP,userEmail,userPasswd,userPremium,char1,char2,char3,char4) VALUES ('admin','lol','somehing','74123',-1,1,-1,-1,-1)```

Comment: That fixed the problem @ChristianMICHON Consider writing an Answer so that I can give you credit for the right answer! Thank you!!

Comment: @Loligans: I've edited my previous answer to match the 2nd fix I suggested. Thanks for the credit